# Facebook Graph API - Getting Data from Subfields

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, get

I have been working on a Facebook app for the last couple of weeks. I have successfully posted data to Facebook's Graph API but I have been struggling to get back specific fields. I am using the API explorer to test my various GET attempts. Here's an excerpt of the data that is returned with the api call: me/g_music:listen_to?fields=data

```
{
  "data": [
{
  "data": {
    "song": {
      "id": "355308601243965", 
      "url": "https://g8-music.herokuapp.com/object/song.php?title=Pierce+The+Veil+-+Bulls+in+the+Bronx&description=Played+On+G8-Music+for+Windows+8.&image=http%3A%2F%2Fuserserve-ak.last.fm%2Fserve%2F174s%2F78366946.jpg", 
      "type": "g_music:song", 
      "title": "Pierce The Veil - Bulls in the Bronx"
    }
  }, 
  "id": "245964195537372"
}, 
{
  "data": {
    "song": {
      "id": "365613963536278", 
      "url": "https://g8-music.herokuapp.com/object/song.php?title=Pierce+The+Veil+-+Kings+for+a+Day+%28feat.+Kellin+Quinn%29&description=Played+On+G8-Music+for+Windows+8.&image=http%3A%2F%2Fuserserve-ak.last.fm%2Fserve%2F174s%2F78366946.jpg", 
      "type": "g_music:song", 
      "title": "Pierce The Veil - Kings for a Day (feat. Kellin Quinn)"
    }
  }, 
  "id": "245961632204295"
},
```

I am attempting to get the value of title but have been unsuccessful so far.

If I try something like: me/g_music:listen_to?fields=data.data... I receive an exception which tells me that "Subfields are not supported by data".

I am relatively new to the graph API so I'm most likely missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing anything. I verified this through the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

> Subfields are not supported by **data**

But you have the whole data, simply fetch the *title* from the array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still having a problem accessing the data, however. I can easily access the id field using 'id' as the key but no value is being returned if I attempt to access title. This is most likely due to my lack of experience with arrays in PHP. My current code goes:

              <?php
  foreach ($listens as $listen)
  {
                      $id = idx($listen, 'id');
                  
              ?>
                  <h4><?php echo he($id); ?></h4>
              <?php
                  }
              ?>

This works fine, but if I change 'id' to 'title' I get no output.

Comment: Try this: `<?php foreach ($listens['data'] as $listen) { $title = $listen['title']; $id = $listen['id'] } ?>`.